# Laravel 5 Cannot Find Driver Postgre SQL

Tags: postgresql, laravel, database-connection, laravel-5

I'm working on a Laravel Project which using a Postgre database, I run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Then I get error

```
[PDPException] could not find driver
```

But all my drivers is properly installled and enabled in my php.ini . I have a Yii Application that uses Postgre and works fine. `php_pdo_pgsql` is already installed and enabled.

Here's my config on Laravel

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PDO Fetch Style
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
| stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
| array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
|
*/

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => 'pgsql',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => '192.168.3.9',
        'database' => 'qms',
        'username' => 'postgres',
        'password' => 'postgres',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],

];
```

Comment: I've also got this problem. What OS are you using? Did you solve this issue? If so, can you add an answer here so others can learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `doctrine/dbal` package to use postgres. https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/dbal

Add this to your application by requiring the package:

`composer require doctrine/dbal`

Comment: Can you go into details about why this needs to be installed and what effect it will have? I've got the same problem as @Joene above, and adding this package didn't have any effect.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, eloquent uses doctrine packages. The dbal one is optional once you install Laravel. This package adds the necessary layer needed for eloquent to talk with psql. Also if this didn't help, I guess your php extension for pdo pgsql is not active.

Comment: Thanks @Luceos, appreciate the info. Annoyingly, I can run queries on PGSQL via. PHP on both my Apache server and through CLI, so it looks like everything is working as it should, just my migrations are showing that error :( Are you sure Eloquent USES Doctrine, or they're a replacement for one another? [See here](http://culttt.com/2014/06/30/getting-started-doctrine-2-laravel/). Is there any official documentation regarding DBAL I can read to figure out if that's what I need before I go too far down that route?

Comment: We use psql for our 4.2 app and had to include the doctrine package for the migrations to work on psql. You might check other suggested packages if the doctrine package has changed via your root composer file. Are you sure you have the pdo pgsql extension installed for php?

Comment: Thanks @Luceos. Yep, for some reason `pdo_pgsql` was appearing in my web `phpinfo()` but not in my CLI, no matter what I did. Connections to PostgreS was successful in both environments, but Laravel was still throwing the error. I've been using WAMP (mainly because I'm comfortable with it), but it hasn't been updated in a while and it's getting long in the tooth. I switched to Laragon and had everything up and going right off the bat. Thanks for your help thus far though.

Comment: And I don't have the above package installed, so I'm not totally sure it's required. Maybe for an older version of Laravel and/or PHP it was needed?

Comment: That could be possible. I'm not sure. For migrations it helped while running laravel 4.2; I only now see the question is for 5. Well maybe other people find a solution in this.